# How can I create a ParallelTable with finer resolution at certain points?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

For example, say I have a function `testfunc` already defined to take one argument $x$. This command would create a table of `testfunc` for $x$ from $0.1$ to $0.9$ in steps of $0.1$:

`ParallelTable[testfunc[x],{x,0.1,0.9,0.1}]`

Suppose I know that `testfunc` varies substantially more between $0.4 < x < 0.5$, so I want the ParallelTable to evaluate that region with more resolution. How can I run the command for $0.1 < x < 0.4, 0.5 < x < 0.9$ in steps of $0.1$, but the middle region in steps of $0.01$?

A first guess is to use something like `ParallelTable[testfunc[x],{x,{Range[0.1,0.4,0.1],Range[0.41,0.49,0.01],Range[0.5,0.9,0.1]}}]`

But it does not give the desired result.

[image]

In this case my desired result would be `{0.1, 0.01},{0.2,0.04},{0.3,0.09},{0.4,0.16},{0.41,0.1681},{0.42,0.1764} ...` etc.

Comment: For your example at least you can use `Join` to merge the different lists, i.e. `ParallelTable[{x, testfunc[x]}, {x, Join[Range[0.1, 0.4, 0.1], Range[0.41, 0.49, 0.01], Range[0.5, 0.9, 0.1]]}]`